# Copy text file from my raspberry pi to windows pc over ssh

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, file-sharing

I am using raspberry pi model 3b boards for my project. These boards are acting as BLE rssi scanners and are storing the rssi data in a text file (saved on desktop).

Now, in order to analyze that data, I need to copy or transfer those text files to my windows pc. I tried the instructions given at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/scp.md BUT it didn't work out. The error says: "Not a regular file".

Please help me regarding the same.

Thanks in Advance,

Aditya

Comment: 1. Can you share more about the error and the file? 2. Can you try copying the file using a Graphical Tool like WinSCP, and share the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see why scp isn't working unless you haven't enabled ssh on both machines. But that aside you could use a Samba file share mounted on one machine from the other, and then just drag and drop. Instructions to set setup a Pi based server are  [here](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/samba-file-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet access and nothing else works try this:
`cat ~/some_file.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`
something like pastebin.